# JavaFX 2.2 Remove Show-Hide-Column Button in TableView and change position of column sort arrow

Tags: css, javafx-2, javafx, tableview

I have two problems with the TableView in JavaFX 2.2. First of all, have a look the following image:

[image]

As you can see I have an TableView with five columns. I used CSS to remove the vertical separators and the background color. However, I cannot remove the right 'column', which is the 'TableMenuButton'. It is somehow connected to the css class `.table-view .show-hide-columns-button` and `.table-view .show-hide-column-image`. I tried to make it transparent, remove the effects and many other things, but with nothing worked out.

The second problem is the sorting arrow in the table header. The column headline is aligned to the left, so I need to display the arrows on the left side as well. Otherwise, the user might think the column to the right is currently sorted (e.g. have a look at the image above). Is there an easy way to do this? I tried `-fx-alignment: left;` and other css commands, but again without any success.

Comment: Doesn't `TableView.setTableMenuButtonVisible(false)` work?

Comment: Thought about this too, but it is not working. However, if recognized that the table menu button column vanishes, if I resize the TableView. Tomorrow I will try to resize the view programmatically.

Comment: I found a solution for my first problem, the table menu button. You can hide it by setting `-fx-border-color: transparent;` for the class `.table-view .filler`.